# Find all solutions for $7x^2 \equiv 3 \mod5$, if any.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

First of all in $\mod5$, the congruence could be reduced to $2x^2 \equiv 3 \mod5$.

Since $2$ is a primitive root for $\mod5$, we have $2i\equiv3 \mod4$.
But $\gcd(2,4)=2$ and $2$ does not divide $3$, hence there are no solutions.

Is this correct? Where would I factor in the $2$ from the original congruence? I suspect there is indeed a solution but my calculation does not take the $2$ from $2x^2 \equiv 3 \mod5$ into consideration. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $2i \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$?

Comment: There are two solutions, $x\equiv \pm 2$.

Comment: No, because when equating the exponents, we have to solve in mod(phi(n))=mod(phi(5))=mod(4).

Comment: Note that there are only $5$ numbers modulo $5$, so finding the solutions directly is always easy.

Answer (score 5):

An easier way than you're attempting: 3 is the multiplicative inverse of 2 modulo 5, so to solve $2x^2 \equiv 3\; (\textrm{mod}\; 5)$, we can multiply through by 3 and look for solutions to $x^2 \equiv 9 \equiv 4\; (\textrm{mod}\; 5)$, whereby we see $x = \pm2$ are the only solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Or, $\ 2x^2\equiv -2\,\Rightarrow\, x^2\equiv -1\equiv 4\,\Rightarrow\,x\equiv \ldots$

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the original equation you have
$$2(y)\equiv 3 \mod 5 \implies y \equiv 4$$
The questions then becomes 
$$x^2 \equiv 4 \mod 5$$ which is true for $x\equiv \pm2$